# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when restarting game

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

Been trying to solve this error for ages now, hoping that someone here can help! :-)

I am using Cocos2d with Objective-C and have a simple game. I have just added a 'restart game' button that takes you back to the main menu so that you can choose to start a new game. The problem is i am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS upon re-starting the game.

```
   [self performSelector:@selector(drawone) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawtwo) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawthree) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawfour) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawfive) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawsix) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawseven) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(draweight) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawnine) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawten) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

I am running the above code in 'init' and this causes the game to crash on the second play through on line

```
-(void)drawone {
```

However, if i am to comment out some of the above code e.g

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(drawone) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawtwo) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawthree) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawfour) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawfive) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

     /* [self performSelector:@selector(drawsix) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawseven) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(draweight) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawnine) withObject:nil afterDelay:3]; */

     [self performSelector:@selector(drawten) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

Then i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on -(void)drawfive this time (still on second play)

Finially, commenting out more of the code e.g

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawone) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

    /*  [self performSelector:@selector(drawtwo) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawthree) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawfour) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawfive) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawsix) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawseven) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(draweight) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
     [self performSelector:@selector(drawnine) withObject:nil afterDelay:3]; */

     [self performSelector:@selector(drawten) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

And it makes it to the 6th play through (you can restart it 5 times) before getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on -(void)drawone

The fact that the EXC_BAD_ACCESS changes places and when it appears leads me to assume that there is not a problem in -(void)drawone since, in some cases, it will run that without problem. I heard that using zombies to debug it could help: after trying unfortunately it did not. I am new to Objective-C so i apologise if this is a simple error. Thank you in advance.

Here is drawone:

```
-(void)drawone
 {

onepos = (arc4random() % 10) + 1;


if(positions[(onepos - 1)] != 0)
{
    positions[(onepos - 1)] = 0;
    if(onepos == 1)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp(53,420);
        [self addChild:onem];

    }
    else if(onepos == 2)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp((53 + (106 * 1)),420);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }
    else if(onepos == 3)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp((53 + (106 * 2)),420);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }
    else if(onepos == 4)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp(53,300);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }
    else if(onepos == 5)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp((53 + (106 * 1)),300);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }
    else if(onepos == 6)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp((53 + (106 * 2)),300);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }
    else if(onepos == 7)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp(53,180);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }
    else if(onepos == 8)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp((53 + (106 * 1)),180);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }
    else if(onepos == 9)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp((53 + (106 * 2)),180);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }
    else if(onepos == 10)
    {
        CCMenuItemImage *one = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"one.png" selectedImage:@"onepressed.png"

                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(oneclick:)];

        onem = [CCMenu menuWithItems:one, nil];
        onem.positionInPixels = ccp((53 + (106 * 1)),60);
        [self addChild:onem];


    }

}
else
{

    [self drawone];

}
```

}

and i have global variables:

```
int positions[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int currentclick = 10; 
int onepos;
NSTimeInterval starttime;
CCMenu* onem;
CCMenu* twom;
CCMenu* threem;
CCMenu* fourm;
CCMenu* fivem;
CCMenu* sixm;
CCMenu* sevenm;
CCMenu* eightm;
CCMenu* ninem;
CCMenu* tenm;
```

Again, i am new to objective-c, so am probably doing something really stupid

Comment: Can you share the code of draw one for example? Also do these methods change any global variables?

Comment: I have added the code and global variables that you requested, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The fact that the EXC_BAD_ACCESS changes places and when it appears
>   leads me to assume that there is not a problem in -(void)drawone
>   since, in some cases, it will run that without problem.

That may or may not be true. The fact that your code doesn't always crash doesn't mean that there's not a problem. EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that your code is accessing a bad pointer somewhere. It sounds like you've got an uninitialized pointer in your code, and your code is crashing whenever that pointer happens to point to an invalid address. If the pointer happens to point to some valid object or contains nil (either of which can easily happen as the result of values left on the stack by other methods) then your code won't crash.

The way to debug this is to get the code to crash, and then use the debugger to look at the code at the point where the crash happened. Take a look at the variables that are used on the line that caused the exception. If the crash happened in some method that's not yours (somewhere in a framework) back up the stack looking for the first place where you can see your code and check that instead.

Comment: The point where the crash happens is on the line -(void)drawone so i cannot tell, if what your saying is correct, which variables are causing the code to crash. The debugger does say 'unable to restore previously selected frame' if that helps at all.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the first line of `-drawone` and step through the code when you hit that breakpoint. Also, try changing your code to call `-drawone` directly instead of using `-performSelector:...`. One possibility is that by the time `-drawone` gets called, `self` has already been released and deallocated.

Comment: How do you mean call it directly? Like [self drawone]?

Comment: @user1232480 - Yes, call directly `[self drawone]; [self drawtwo]; ...` without `performSelector`. Put a breakpoint (marked with blue in Xcode) and do as Caleb said. We need the know the line where the app crashes and the debugger message.

Comment: The problem with putting breakpoints is that the problem appears on restarting the game. A breakpoint would effect the first run through and so the game never makes it to the 'restart' screen: unless I'm missing some obvious feature that allows me to make this work.

Comment: ^never mind, got it. Will get back to you when found the problem.

Comment: Ok, worked through addone using breakpoints as suggested. The code appears to be failing on the                                       line  `if(positions[(onepos - 1)] != 0)` right near the top.

Comment: Never mind, got this working. For some reason the array (named positions) was causing the problem so just got rid of it and re-programmed it without the array. Thanks to all for helping me debug this error. :-)